# How to effectively use HTTPClient (.Net 4.5) for sending request to different servers?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am working with legacy ASP.NET application and would like to use HTTPClient to send HTTP requests to handful of different servers (that is, with different BaseAddresses). I have read lot of posts saying single HTTPClient instance should be used for lifetime of application to avoid "sockets exhaustion". But I think, in this case, using same instance for sending requests to different servers might not be viable.

So instead I am thinking of writing a simple factory method, that will accept the baseaddress and will either return a new (if it doesn't exist already) or an existing instance of HTTPClient pre-configured for that specific base-address.

Further calls on HTTPClient instance would be made from an ASP.Net page and since a page could be requested simultaneously by multiple users, I wonder would there be issue with concurrent connections exceeding the maximum limit set on HTTPClient underlying ServicePoint (which is by default 2 for non ASP.Net hosts).

Can someone suggest, if using factory method approach sounds good enough or is there any better solution to tackle this? Also do I need to consider setting concurrent connections limit to some higher value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no need to create a new instance. A factory is *already* available through [HttpClientFactory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) which targets .NET Standard 2.0. As for the ServicePoint limit, it exists because way back when, it was expected that *browsers* shouldn't have to send more than 2 concurrent requests to servers. It's the *servers* that may go down or throttle chatty clients if they make too many concurrent requests

Comment: Thanks! HTTPClientFactory works with dependency injection and unfortunately application is too old that they did not use any DI framework. Changing the design now would not be good choice.

Comment: it doesn't *need* Dependency injection. Using DI makes it a lot easier though, and it's actually *easy* to use DI in older applications - instead of new-ing something, pass it as a constructor parameter. Even in .NET Core, you shouldn't have to access the DI container except at the top level. Worst case, you can create a singleton factory

Comment: Even if you create you own factory, you'd have to put it *somewhere* so the code can access it - create a Singleton perhaps? It's no different with HttpClientFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An `HttpClient` instance ***per host*** is totally appropriate here. Socket exhaustion typically happens at a number in the thousands; you should be fine with a "handful" of hosts. And a socket is specific to 1 host anyway, so you gain nothing in terms of socket conservation by using a single `HttpClient` instance with multiple hosts.
2. Yes, I would definitely consider boosting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` in this scenario. How high? Depends on your scenario obviously, but with most hosting environments 100 or even more should be perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that is what I meant, maintaining and reusing one instance **per host** rather than creating a new instance **per request**.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it. Your question was basically "is this a good idea?" and I'm basically saying yes it probably is :)